# How do I set the time on an android digitalClock?

Tags: android, time, digital

I'm creating an android application that gets the current time in a different country/time-zone. I'm making it as there aren't many other apps on the marketplace that do the same job.

I've got an digitalClock  underneath on my app, how do I change the time on the clock - take on or off a number of hours? For example, I may want the clock to display the time in another country.

Please excuse the simple questions!

Comment: `DigitalClock` is deprecated, but if you use [`TextClock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html), you can set the timezone using [`setTimeZone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html#setTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: unforchinetly, my android version does not support TextClock,

Comment: Have you got any solution alse to help me?

Comment: Well, `DigitalClock` has an `updateTime` method which takes a `Calendar`, so maybe you can create an offset calendar and pass it to this method.